# "Both a" vs "a both"

Tags: grammar

I'm unsure about the grammatically correct use of the word "both" in the following sentence.

The text currently reads:

> This is **a both** natural and powerful thing

Which sounds weird to me. I think that:

> This is **both a** natural and powerful thing

sounds better, but I'm not a 100% sure and as such hesitant to change the sentence.

Which is the correct version? Or are both sentences grammatically valid? If so, are there any subtle differences in their semantics (like in e.g., "fine with me" vs. "fine for me")?

Comment: "...both a natural and a powerful thing"... But "both" is filler and could be removed without any loss of meaning.

Comment: _This is a [both natural and powerful] thing_ = _This is [both a natural and a powerful]] thing_

Comment: @JohnLawler **both** is a predeterminer, so isn't it be wrong to put the central determiner - **a** - before a predeterminer - **both**?

Comment: "Predeterminer" is not a fact, nor a rule, but somebody's label. You can't determine anything from an arbitrary label; certainly it won't help you determine wrong from right.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks, but one more thing I've observed it's very rare in COCA in such construction where *a* is before *both*.

Comment: Though that doesn't mean it's incorrect. But not adhering to that predeterminer thing is really strange! Anyway everything has exception, why doesn't it be? :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can avoid the problem by saying what is really behind your constructions:

> This is a thing both natural and powerful.

But you might find this a phraseology too rhetorical and antiquated. It scans nicely, though.

Comment: That looks odd for adjectives which usually come before the noun.  Perhaps "This thing is both natural and powerful" as an alternative

Comment: Oh yes. I agree.

Comment: No! Don't listen to Henry. "A thing both both natural and powerful" is a beautiful phrase *because* the phrasing is unusual. To only use the most obvious and everyday forms is akin to serving only boiled potatoes and no meat. Our lives will be the poorer for it.

Comment: Agree with @mikeagg, with the caveat that it depends on context: what type of writing is this, what type of writer are you, what flows better in the overall structure of the prose and what sort of style is expected by your audience. In the wrong context, the first phrasing (which I also prefer absent other information) becomes flowery and, perhaps, a bit heavy.

Comment: @mikeagg: I agree with you, too :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are technically grammatically valid, but I prefer the second, "both a," for a couple of reasons. First, as you say, it just sounds/looks better, perhaps simply because it's more often formulated with "both" first? I do think there's a slight semantic difference, too, or perhaps, better put, a difference in emphasis. Putting "both" directly after "is" emphasizes the sentence's focus on the description of the thing's dual nature, while putting "a" in between minutely breaks the rhetorical flow of the sentence, and to my eye throws a bit more weight onto the final "thing"--i.e. "This is a...thing."

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is slightly different here, even if it is just about emphasizing.

> 1. **This is a** *(pause)* **both natural and powerful thing.**
> 2. **This is both** *(pause)* **a natural and powerful thing.**

Imagine a discussion or talk about natural and/or powerful things. At the end of the discussion saying

- the 1. sentence emphasizes what it is, *"**natural and powerful**"*. In this case you could leave *"both"*.
- the 2. sentence emphassizes that it is *"**both**"*. Here you could drop *"a natural and powerful thing"*.

Of course this is a very little difference, but e.g. as the last sentence of a statement, this might tip the scales, if someone wants to point out the thing being both itself is most important, or it having the actual qualities.

In other contexts it might not matter at all, so there **can** but **must not** be a difference.